# How can I stop matching until first specific character?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my pattern ([Live example](https://regex101.com/r/wqmwDp/4)):

```
(?:&quot;|")id(?:&quot;|"):(?:&quot;|")(.{0,200}?)(?:&quot;|").{0,200}?(?:&quot;|")urn:li:fs_miniCompany:65514(?:&quot;|")
```

As you can see, it matches following string as first capturing group:

```
/p/3/005/07a/356/1399435.png&quot;,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorImage&quot;,&quot;$id&quot;:
```

But this is expected result:

```
/p/3/005/07a/356/1399435.png
```

How can I do that?

---

**Note:** I can use `[^&]+` to stop matching, but in this case, it throws `Catastrophic Backtracking` error.

Comment: Noted that [this](https://regex101.com/r/wqmwDp/5) is my real data.

Comment: What you want to extract is inside structured data, use the structure. 1) parse the html to extract the content of `code` tags using `DOMDocument`. 2) replace `&quote;` with `"`. 3) decode the json and follow its structure to find what you want.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I see, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a string approach when you have structured data. You are actually searching something inside a JSON string that is inside an html `<code>` tag.
Extracting the `<code>` tag text that contains the substring `"urn:li:fs_miniCompany:65514"` using XPath is an easy task that will drastically reduce the search area.

Then all you need to do is to make little changes to obtain a JSON string *(trimming unwanted characters and replacing the `&quote;` entity with a double quote)*

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('yourfile.html'); // or $dom->loadHTML($yourstring);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$codeContent = $xp->evaluate('string(//code[contains(., "urn:li:fs_miniCompany:65514")])');

$json = str_replace('&quote;', '"', trim($codeContent, "\r\n \t\\n"));
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

print_r(array_column($arr['included'], 'id'));
```

You only have to find how to choose the one you want according to the json structure *(use `print_r($arr)` to visualize it)*.

---

General considerations about your pattern:

- avoid to start a pattern with an alternation *(I don't see any reason to write `(?:&quote;|")` since each quote seems to be replaced by its html entity. `&quote;` should suffice.)* When there is no other ways:

  - try to use the STUDY modifier: `/pattern/S`
  - try to use the first character discrimination technique building your pattern this way: `/(?=[&"])(?:&quote;|").../` or this way: `/[&"](?:(?<=&)quote;|(?<=")).../`
  - in the worst case try two patterns *(starting a pattern with a literal string provides an high improvement since a fast algorithm find all positions where the pattern may succeed, before the regex engine starts its normal walk)*.
- `a.*b.*c` *(as `a.*?b.*?c` or `a.{1,n}b.{1,n}c` or `a.{1,n}?b.{1,n}?c`)* is a well know source of catastrophic backtracking. This kind of pattern allows too many combinations for a single position in the subject string, and it takes many steps and time before failing since each combination is tested.
- try to write a pattern that fails as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead to match everything except a sequence of characters. I would also advise against useing `{0,200}` because it seems to be rather random. This pattern matches the first PNG path. If you want to have the last one, I would use a more specific selector instead of useing `{0,200}`:

```
(?:&quot;|")id(?:&quot;|"):(?:&quot;|")(.*?)(?:&quot;|").*?(?!&quot;).*?(?:&quot;|")urn:li:fs_miniCompany:65514(?:&quot;|")
```

- Here is your updated example: https://regex101.com/r/wqmwDp/9
- And here, it matches the correct PNG (shrinken the sample text): https://regex101.com/r/wqmwDp/8